# Generate identifier for subgroups based on one row in a subgroup

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with data from multiple experiments with multiple conditions. In each of these, there are multiple periods and multiple subjects who interact in these periods.

My data looks as follows (first five columns):

```
Experiment Condition Period Subject   E    G   GNew
     1         1        1      1     20    1     1
     1         1        1      2     60    2     2
     1         1        1      3     20    1     1
     1         1        1      4     60    2     2
     1         1        2      1     23   NA     1
     1         1        2      2     45   NA     2
     1         1        2      3     13   NA     1
     1         1        2      4     20   NA     2
     1         2        1      1     50    3     3
     1         2        1      2     50    3     3
     1         2        1      3     40    4     4
     1         2        1      4     50    3     3
     1         2        2      1     23   NA     3
     1         2        2      2     45   NA     3
     1         2        2      3     13   NA     4
     1         2        2      4     20   NA     3
```

I now want to generate a variable GNew which groups subjects into groups depending on the value E in the first period within the same experiment and condition.

I have succeeded in generating the column G but what I would like is to end up with a variable like GNew, which assigns a group number to each subject based on their value in E in the first period, but contains this number in every period. Different experiments and conditions are independent of each other and should receive different group numbers GNew, as in the data shown above.

I can achieve this with nested for-loops, but I am sure there is a more elegant solution using `aggregate`, `by`, `apply`, `data.table` or some such. I have googled for this for a while now, but the solution yet eludes me.

Comment: How are the values of `GNew` achieved? I can't see the logic behind giving values `23, 45, 20` in `E` the same value in `GNew` (last four rows).

Comment: @LAP Because the same subjects in period 1 in the 2nd Condition take this `rank` or `order`

Comment: Ah yeah, I can't read properly. Thanks @A.Suliman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tidyverse not forbidden, you could do a `group_by`, then `arrange`, then a `mutate` selecting the first element within each group.

```
data %>%
    group_by(Experiment, Condition) %>% 
    arrange(E) %>%
    mutate(Gnew = E[1]) %>% 
    ungroup() -> data
```

(n.b. not tested)

Comment: Looking again, you might not be wanting to do the arrange, as perhaps you don't want the lowest `E` for each Experiment-Condition combination?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I run that, Gnew equals the first entry of E within each experiment and condition. I have now modified the second line to read `group_by(Experiment, Condition, Subject) %>%`. Now Gnew correctly contains the value of a subject's E in the first period. I would now create an identifier from it by using: `temp<-unique(data[data$Period==1,c("Experiment","Condition","Gnew")])` and `temp$Gnew1<-1:nrow(temp)` and `data<-merge(data,temp[,c("Experiment","Condition","Gnew1")],all.x=T)` (not yet tested). Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Sorry, that was unnecessarily complicated. `Sbj$Gnew1<-as.numeric(as.factor(Sbj$Gnew))` should do the trick.

Comment: data %>%
    group_by(Experiment, Condition, Subject) %>% 
    arrange(E) %>%
    mutate(Gnew = E[1]) %>% 
    mutate(Gnew = paste(Experiment, Condition, Gnew, sep = "\_") %>% 
    ungroup() -> data

or something like that.

i.e. you can use paste to join the contents of multiple columns together, and perhaps something like "_" as separator so you can tell which parts came from Experiment, Condition, and Subject.

Comment: This `as.numeric(factor(as.character(data$Gnew), unique(as.character(data$Gnew))))` will end @JonMinton brilliant solution. Also I think there is no need for `arrange`.